# Java return byte array

Tags: java, android

```
public static void main (){
    byte[] a = get();
    byte[] b = {1,2,3,4};

    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 2, 2);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 0, 2);
}

public static byte[] get(){
    byte c={5,6}; // byte c= new byte[2];...
    return c;
}
```

My question is: what the difference between returning `byte c={5,6}` and `byte c=new byte[2]; c[0]=5;c[1]=6;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare array (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-java) and btw `byte c={5,6};` wont work. It must be `byte[] c={5,6};`

Comment: Apart from the fact that the first is a static initializer, there is none. Why?

Comment: despite the fact that this wont compile, since `c` is declared to be a `byte` and not a `byte` array, there is none, both create a new array.

Comment: There is no difference, the resulting bytecode will use the same instruction (newarray).

Comment: sorry guys, for I post it by my phone, so ... eh...sorry for my miss typing ;)

Comment: Are they both stored in heap or stack?

Comment: You can here find some information about the [shortcut syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). As @Jean-FrançoisSavard said they will be compiled to the same bytecode.

Comment: @SubOptimal thx a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

`c={5,6}` initializes the array with an array of size 2, and values "5" and "6".
`c=new byte[2]` initializes the array with an array of size 2, and values **0** and **0**.

Comment: primitives can´t be `null`